# Static UI header element needs to remain in view when on-screen keyboard is opened for a RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, vertical-scrolling, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to change the behaviour when there's on-screen keyboard presence similar to what is described on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 but not actually clarified as to how to achieve:

> In some cases, there are UI elements that should stay on the screen
>   the entire time. Design the UI so that the form controls are contained
>   in a panning region and the important UI elements are static.

This is my page's basic xaml layout:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="titlebar" Grid.Row="0" />

    <RichEditBox x:Name="content" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

What I want is for the titlebar element to still be visible on-screen when the touch-screen keyboard is opened. At the moment, what's happening is when the on-screen keyboard is called, the page is automatically scrolled down so that the RichEditBox appears at the very top of my view (requiring me to scroll up in order to get the titlebar back into view).

Any guidance on how to achieve the behaviour I'm after will be much appreciated.

Comment: What about wrapping your Layout into a `ScrollViewer`? You could subscribe to `InputPane.Showing` + `Hiding` and call `ScrollViewer.ChangeView` with the desired Y-position to ensure the titlebar is the top element.

Answer (score 0):

Put both header TextBlock and RichTextBox in a Grid and then use translateY on the Grid's transform when RichTextBox receive focus.

Maybe something like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/99652e87-113c-47fa-a8e7-60f11fc9f160/virtual-keyboard-covering-textbox

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/08/windows-8-xaml-manipulation-using.html?m=1